# Lookup for some object

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

I have a picklist that contains list of viable objects like account and user, for example, and I want, based on value of this picklist, make "lookup" for records of this object. I thought of somehow utilizing apex:inputfields. But it seems like it won't work. Similar functionality realized in email templates when user test them with existing data, but I haven't come up with idea how to mimic it.

Comment: What functionality / requirement do you want to solve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just fire the action function when user change his selection, perform the query like this one:

```
String objectName = 'someObject'; // object name retrieved from picklist
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM :objectName');
```

Then fill some collection in your VF page and rerender it. Using the ids of the objects, you could create a lookup links as well.